# Does Galilean/Newtonian mechanics reject both consequences of Aristotle's dynamical pseudo-law : $ V = F/m$, or only consequence (1)?

Tags: classical-mechanics, newton, galileo

Note : my question is not as to whether consequence (2) is correctly derived from Arstotle's "law" ( I think it is the case) but as to whether this consequence is still true in Newtonian physics ( though deriving from a false principle). In short : ***are both consequences false in Newtonian physics, or only consequence (1)?***

---

As says the Stanford physicist who co-authored the *Theoretical Minimum*, Aristotle lived in a world of frictions ( but was unaware of this), and thus believed that movement  naturally tends to rest, meaning that a force is needed to maintain an object is a state of motion.

Hence, his dynamical views ( Aristotle's ones of course, not the Stanford physicist's ) can be summarized by this formula :

$$ V = \frac{F} {m}.$$

This "law" entails two consequences

$(1)$ If $F = 0$, then $V=0$.

$(2)$ If $V= 0$, then $F=0$.

Modern physics ( in the sense of "post medieval physics") shows that consequence $(1)$ is false , or at least negates this consequence, which is enough to force the rejection of the alleged Aristotelian law.

> My question is simply : is consequence $(2)$ correct ( in spite of the
> falsiy of the principle from which it is derived)?

I believe it is the case but I want to make sure.

The reasoning I'd propose to show that consequence $(2)$ is correct is as follows ( with $V(t) =$ the velocity function , and $A(t)$ the acceleration function).

Suppose $V(t)=0$. in that case $V'(t) = 0$. But $V'(t)=A(t)$.So $A(t)=0$.

By Newton's second law : $A(t)= \frac {F(t)} {m}$.

Hence :  $ A(t)= 0$ implies $\frac {F(t)} {m}=0$, which implies finally $ F(t)=0$.

Is this rigorous enough? In particular, is it enough to state the equations in terms of scalar quantities to show that the result holds?

Comment: Newton Law, which you use in derivation of (2) assumes that there is no friction. In the presence of friction (2) is simply not true, as you can convince yourself by trying to push a car with parking brake applied.

Comment: What's the basis _in Aristotle_ for saying that " V = F/m " summarises Aristotle's views, and what basis is there _in Aristotle_ to know what "m" means?

Comment: $V(t)=0$ does not imply $A(t)=V'(t)=0$, you need $V(s)=0$ for $s$ on some interval around $t$ to get that. This is reflected in the fact that initial position *and velocity* have to be specified to find equations of motion when the forces are given. And $F(0)\neq0$ may well be the case even though $V(0)=0$, so $(2)$ is false as well.

Comment: Provided that there where no A's laws in algebraic form (still Galileo does **not** use algebraic form) we have to consider *static* See Pseudo-Aristotle's [Mechanica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanics_(Pseudo-Aristotle)). See also Joyce van Leeuwen, The Aristotelian Mechanics Text and Diagrams (Springer, 2016)

Comment: See [847b](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Aristotle/Mechanica*.html): "Among the problems included in this class are included those concerned with the lever. For it is strange that a great weight can be moved by a small force, and that, too, when a greater weight is involved. For the very same weight, which a man cannot move without a lever, he quickly moves by applying the weight of the lever." This statement implies that there are cases when a force applied does not produce movement.

Comment: As regards car - you need friction to move it (think of car on ice).

Comment: The second thing is not always correct. I think you're forgetting to account for force and velocity being vectors. If theres a car coming towards the Hulk and he smashes it to a halt. V_init > 0. V_final = 0. F_init = 0. F_final > 0